# Php simplexml load string xmlParseCharRef: invalid xmlChar value 25

Tags: php, xml, curl

When I load a large xml file of 13000 records I experience

> Error loading XML xmlParseCharRef: invalid xmlChar value 25
>   xmlParseCharRef: invalid xmlChar value 25

But when I load a smaller xml file it works fine ..

Does anyone know what the above refers to ?

If I alternatively try and save the xml using

```
 $xml->asXml($filename);
```

it works fine for the smaller xml but for the larger one It gives

> Error: Call to a member function asXml() on boolean

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($result, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOERROR |  
LIBXML_ERR_NONE);

            if (!$xml) {
                echo "Error loading XML\n";
                foreach (libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
                    echo "\t", $error->message;
                }
            }

print_r($xml);
```

Answer (score 0):

it's probably too big for the default settings, use the flag `LIBXML_PARSEHUGE` to parse.. `huge` files.